# can I replace multiline like this in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I want keep my js in this style. I want write a map in vim to do it faster.

from:

```
var a = x;
var b = y;
var c = z;
```

to:

```
var a = x
  , b = y
  , c = z
  ;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the following command.

`%s/;\nvar /\r  , /gc`

Comment: +1. The trick is to use `\r` in the replacement. Bites me (close to) every time.

Answer (score 0):

My solution in a case like this would be

1. position cursor on first `var` (e.g. <kbd>{</kbd>)
2. **1f;<kbd>C-v</kbd>jr,w<kbd>C-v</kbd>jexkJJ**

For info, the Align script has the inverse operation:

```
var a = x, b = y, c = z;
```

1. <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Leader</kbd><kbd>a,</kbd>, result:

```
var a = x;
var b = y;
var c = z;
```